# How can I get Maven to generate a jnlp for my project?

Tags: java, maven-2, build

I'd like to have Maven2 generate a .jnlp (webstart profile) for my application.

There is a maven-jnlp-plugin, but it's deprecated as of somewhere around Maven 1.1-beta2.

Is there a more preferred way to do this, or do I need to build out this capability myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And there is [webstart-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/) for maven2

Comment: In case someone still want to use this plugin. it work only with maven 2, not with maven 3 (as of 1.0-beta3)

Comment: And it seems to be discontinued meanwhile. Despite the documentation is up, the plugin is not available for Maven to download. Sad, as https://openwebstart.com is available.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [JFrog WebStart and JavaFX plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/JP/JavaFX+Compiler+Maven+Plugin) which can keep maven2 layout for your dependencies !

Comment: It appears that this is not available from Maven Central but only from JFrog itself.  That is unfortunately a show stopper for us.