# Using Maven to build a Java Web Start application

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, java-web-start

I'm new to almost all related things, but would like to build a Java Web Start application using Maven. I also need to repack a specific .jar (commons-httpclient-3.1.jar), or it won't sign with JarSigner (looks to be a common problem when I googled). Perhaps I could use [this](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo.webstart%22%20AND%20a%3A%22webstart-maven-plugin%22) Maven plugin, but I don't even know how to setup the Maven repository.

I (might) need to:

- set up the Maven repository to be able to use the above plugin,
- configure the jnlp build using the plugin,
- take use of three .jars that we have developed (already built using Maven) and install along with the dependencies (such as slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar and a dozen or so others),
- also unpack and repack a specific .jar (repack using jar.exe, not zip since it doesn't work).

I much prefer examples to links to big chunks of documentation. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"..need to repack a specific .jar .. or it won't sign with JarSigner"*  Because it is digitally signed?  Put it in a JWS extension (the [`component-desc` element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#comp_desc)) and add a reference to the extension in the main JNLP.  The rule is that all Jars in *each extension* need to have the same digital signature.

Comment: Relevant topics: [Looking for Webstart Maven Plugin sample application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195545), [How can I get Maven to generate a jnlp for my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842959).

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [maven plugin for web start](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/)

Alternatively you can generate a war with the jnlp file inside (created manually)

You can even create a servlet that will create a jnlp (with stuff like get all jars in some lib directory) and return dynamically to the client.

The plugin should be in the maven repository, but I've never checked it...

Comment: That's the same plugin I'm referring to, but I don't know how to refer to the repository within the <repositories> tag in pom.xml, what URL and ID should I use? How do I find out?

Comment: This thing is rather related to overall maven configuration and not specific to web start. As a first attempt just use defaults (there is a default repository, assuming you're not behind a firewall or something). The plugin should exist in the repository you just need to configure it in your application's pom.xml (just like, say, war plugin that you're about to use anyway) and everything should work. How this helps

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but plugin repositories are referenced with a separate configuration in your pom to the normal installation repositories.

e.g.

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

See here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html