# Java Swing Maven Project Deployment with JNLP

Tags: java, swing, maven, deployment, jnlp

I developed a Maven project with Java swing. I want to publish with a JNLP. What should I do in the pom.xml file, don't without using a plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842959/how-can-i-get-maven-to-generate-a-jnlp-for-my-project

Comment: It is possible to do this don't without using the plugin, this is the question I am wondering. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be such support in the standard. However, *webstart-maven-plugin* can be used under *org.codehaus.mojo*.

You can visit the sample for more information and usage : https://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/jnlp-mojos-overview.html